# Automate 25 reports running from sql server every weekend

Tags: sql-server

I have 25 reports those results i need to pull from Sql Server 2008. As of now for 25 reports i have Sql Scripts are ready and i am running individually and copying the each report results into Microsoft Excel each tab.

What is the best way to automate these 25 reports run every week and results should be populated into Excel sheets.

The main purpose of these 25 reports are Clean up reports. business team working on these reports on every week, gradually the results should be less going forward after fixing the data.

Appreciate Your response.

Thanks,
MSS

Comment: it's been a while since i used  EXCEL but can't you simply create the workbook with the 25 spread sheets, and associate the DataSource with the proper query to each worksheet to pull the data? if the query needs parameters than you probably need to do a little VBS magic to read the params from specific cells, but that's trivial. After that updating the workbook should update the data

Comment: 25 queries not having any parameters.

Comment: Personally, I'd just use SSRS.  You can create Excel reports with multiple tabs beginning with 2008 R2, and you can schedule reports as well.

Comment: Sounds like a job for [Reporting Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one possible solution; there are many others depending on your exact requirements...

I suggest this method since it sounds like your reports are just SQL statements; this will give the least-effort solution for automating what you're currently doing manually.

1) Create a text file per report with this file holding the SQL statement:

```
--Filename: Statement1.sql
--example report/query

select c.name CustomerName
, sum(o.amount) OrderTotal
from Customer c
inner join CustomerOrder o
on o.CustomerId = c.Id
order by c.name
```

2) Create a flat file (`reports.csv`) containing the filenames of all of the above reports, and the sheet name for the output:

```
SqlScriptFile,SheetName
Statement1.sql,CustomerOrderTotals
Statement2.sql,AverageCustomerSpend
anotherStatement.sql,Sheet3
```

3) Use the below powershell script (`Run-Reports.ps1`) to run these statements.

```
param 
(
    [string]$DbInstance = 'myDbServer\myInstance'
    ,
    [string]$DbCatalog = 'myDatabase'
    ,
    [string]$ScriptListFilename = 'reports.csv'
    ,
    [string]$OutputExcelFilename = 'MyReports.xlsx'
    ,
    [string]$Delimiter = ','
)

function Execute-SQL
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbInstance
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$DbCatalog 
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$Query   
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]$CommandTimeoutSeconds = 30
    )
    begin
    {
        $connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        $connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$DbInstance;Database=$DbCatalog;Integrated Security=True"
        $connection.Open()
    }
    process
    {
        $command = $connection.CreateCommand()
        $command.CommandTimeout = $CommandTimeoutSeconds
        $command.CommandText = $Query
        $result = $command.ExecuteReader()
        $table = new-object System.Data.DataTable
        $table.Load($result)
        $table | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty RowError, RowState, Table, ItemArray, HasErrors
    }
    end
    {
        $connection.Close()    
    }
}

function Create-ExcelOuputObject
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$SheetName
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [scriptblock]$DataGenerator
    )
    process
    {
        write-output (new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property @{
            SheetName = $SheetName
            DataGenerator = $DataGenerator
        })
    }    
}

function Out-ExcelSheet
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        $WorkSheet
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)]
        [string[]]$Header = $null
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSCustomObject]$DataRow
    )
    begin
    {
        [long]$r = 0
    }
    process
    {
        $r++
        [long]$c = 0
        if($Header -eq $null) 
        {
            $Header = $DataRow | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty | select -ExpandProperty Name
            $Header | 
            %{
                $c++
                $WorkSheet.cells.Item($r,$c) = $_
            }  
            $r++
            $c = 0
        }
        $Header | 
        %{
            $c++
            $WorkSheet.cells.Item($r,$c) = $DataRow."$_"
        }
    }
}

function Out-Excel
{
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param
    (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$OutFilename
        ,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true, ValueFromPipeline = $true)]
        [PSCustomObject]$ExcelOuputObject
    )
    begin
    {
        $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
        $excel.DisplayAlerts = $False
        $excel.Visible = $true
        $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()
        $workbook.Sheets.Count..2 | %{$workbook.Sheets[$_].Delete()}
        $sheet = $workbook.Sheets[1]
    }
    process
    {
        $sheet.Name = $ExcelOuputObject.SheetName
        $ExcelOuputObject.DataGenerator.Invoke() | Out-ExcelSheet -WorkSheet $sheet
        $sheet = $workbook.Sheets.Add()
    }
    end
    {
        $sheet.Delete()
        #$workbook.Sheets[$workbook.Sheets.Count].Delete()
        $OutFilename = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($OutFilename)
        $workbook.SaveAs($OutFilename)
    }
}

clear-host
[PSCustomObject[]]$Reports = Import-Csv $ScriptListFilename -Delimiter $Delimiter
$Reports | 
%{
    [string]$Query = Get-Content $_.SqlScriptFile
    $scriptBlockString = "Execute-SQL -DbInstance '$DbInstance' -DbCatalog '$DbCatalog' -Query @""`n$Query`n""@"
    Create-ExcelOuputObject `
    -SheetName $_.SheetName `
    -DataGenerator ([scriptblock]::Create($scriptBlockString))
} | Out-Excel -OutFilename $OutputExcelFilename
```

4) Use the windows task scheduler to run this schedule this report.
See http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/08/11/weekend-scripter-use-the-windows-task-scheduler-to-run-a-windows-powershell-script.aspx for more information on this piece.

---

**Other Options**

- @[MrE] mentions the Excel Data Source.  This would allow your users to open a spreadsheet that has its content linked to the SQL source; so you can hit refresh and see the latest data.  If you didn't want users accessing the live database, the query is complex and time consuming, or you need the data as of a fixed point in time you could schedule a task to output the results of the queries to dedicated tables (perhaps in another database to help segregate security) then point Excel at those.  More info: https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Connect-a-SQL-Server-database-to-your-workbook-22c39d8d-5b60-4d7e-9d4b-ce6680d43bad
- @[Bacon Bits] advised SSRS.  If you have SSRS development skills this is a good choice as it's a reporting solution designed for SQL, and allows you to create subscriptions (scheduled jobs which can mail the result to users).  More Info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx
- @[Nick.McDermaid] spoke of the SQL Agent.  This is ideal if you want to need to schedule a task to run the reports to reporting tables (as mentioned in my Excel comment above), or to have the system mail the results.  If you need integration with PowerShell (as per my main answer) it's less well placed as this would require enabling cmdshell (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175046.aspx) which is a security risk.  More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms191439.aspx
- Given you're using this information to aid data cleansing activities, another option may be to create a dashboard over this data so that when data's fixed it's automatically removed from the dashboard, helping those working on it to see what others have resolved in real time.  There are a number of toolsets which could create such a dashboard; one that I found after a quick Google is http://htsql.org/; though you could equally build something using .Net technologies (e.g. using ASP.Net, or if you're less familiar with coding the simpler LightSwitch solution: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn284529.aspx).
- Many, many more.

Comment: Excellent detailed response. Another option, given that this is SQL Server, is to use the SQL Server Agent to schedule and manage.

Comment: Thanks John. I will follow your steps. I will let you know if I have any difficulties. I am going to try this in my office machine/desktop. we have all the Production/Testing client server access. I can't  deploy any solutions in production/Testing server. Hope i can implement this solution in my office desktop.

Comment: Yes, it shouldwoen on any machine running powershell and Excel. I`ve only tested against powershell v4 with .net 4.5, but suspect it should work with earlier versions. Good luck.